# Unable to install Yarn on Windows

Tags: windows, npm, yarnpkg

I have Windows 10:

```
$ node -v
v16.14.0
$ npm -v
8.3.1
```

I run in terminal

```
$ npm install yarn -g

changed 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 666ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

but Yarn is not installed

```
$ yarn
C:\Users\G023911\AppData\Roaming\npm/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
```

I can't find anything helpful that shows why it is not working for me.

Comment: Try restarting the cli you're using?

Comment: I restarted everything :/

Answer (score 1):

You should only do that :

1. If Node.js >=16.10 (yarn >= 2.0) : `corepack enable` // else if Node.js <16.10 (yarn 1.0) : `npm install --global yarn`
2. Restart your terminal and your editor (all windows) if you using the terminal inside
3. Check installation with `yarn --version` but if you have npm it will works for sure (I have installed it many times on Windows and Linux this way & it's on the [official 1.0 doc](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable)  and [official 2.0+ doc](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install) !

Comment: Hello, 
I have node v16.14.0 so what means corepack enable?

Comment: As the `2.0+` yarn doc explain:
"Corepack is included by default with all Node.js installs, but is currently opt-in. To enable it, run the following command: `corepack enable`  "
[More info](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install)

Comment: I'm getting error anyway
$ corepack enable
Internal Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\pnpm'
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\pnpm

Comment: @jesetera If you're using visual studio code, cmd, or Windows Terminal, close it and run it in administrator mode. Usually, the reason for that error message is a result of limited privilege giving to the editor or npm or Yarn if you're using that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I installed yarn from the download file in the official github repo
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v1.22.4/yarn-1.22.4.msi (check for a newer version)

Then I had to CLOSE code editor and terminal. Starting new tab wasn't enough, I had to close them and open new ones.

Starting new ones while the old are open didn't work. Close the current code editor and terminal, start new ones, check yarn --version

Answer (score 0):

same issue with mine, that means yarn is installed on your machine but yarn's executable directory is not in system's PATH.

follow steps below:

1. check yarn installation directory:
   `npm bin -g`
2. add yarn's installation directory (generated from previous step `path/to/your/yarn/bin`) to system path

- Linux/MacOS:
  Add
  `export PATH="PATH:/path/to/yarn/bin"`
  to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshhrc` or `~/.bash_profile`
- Windows:
  Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment variables
  Edit **PATH** variable to include the directory (`path/to/your/yarn/bin`).

3. Restart Terminal or Command Prompt or Git Bash
4. Verify yarn Installation
   `yarn --version`

those solved my problem